# Spock: Error when parsing input data in where block

Tags: input, groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

I have the following where block:

```
where:
    [area,country,port,dest_area,dest_country,dest_port] << ["アジア" , "日本", "東京（成田・羽田）", "アジア" ,"韓国" , "ソウル"]
```

And getting  error like this:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at jp.co.skygate.groovy.test.AOSearchPageExternalInputDataTest.Select origin(AOSearchPageExternalInputDataTest.groovy:105)

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
at jp.co.skygate.groovy.test.AOSearchPageExternalInputDataTest.Select origin(AOSearchPageExternalInputDataTest.groovy:105)
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Post the whole source code of the unit test, not just the where: block

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that,
in where block , every variable is populated with a list of values.

```
where:
    [area,country,port,dest_area,dest_country,dest_port] << ["アジア" , "日本", "東京（成田・羽田）", "アジア" ,"韓国" , "ソウル"]
```

should be like this:

```
where:
[area] << ["アジア" ]
[country] << ["日本"]
[port] << ["東京（成田・羽田）"]
[dest_area,] << ["アジア"]
[dest_country] << ["韓国"]
[dest_port] << ["ソウル"]
```